# spresense LTE拡張ボードでLTEとADを使うとLTE.shutdown()でエラーになる

Tags: spresense, arduino

spresense + LTE拡張ボードにて LTE拡張ボード上のアナログピンA4を読み込んだ後
LTE接続してUDPでデータ送信、その後にlteAccess.shutdown()を行うとエラーで停止してしまいます。
analogReadをしなければエラー発生せずに正常に動作します。

LTEの接続送受信と アナログ読み込みの順序を入れ替えると１度は正常にLTE接続-送信-シャットダウンを行いますが
アナログ読み込み後は失敗してしまいます。

LTEを接続したままであればUDP送信は何度でもできるのですが
送信周期が1時間以上空くことと省電力化のためにLTEをOFFにしておきたいのですが
なにか対処方法はありますでしょうか？

エラー検証用に抜き出して確認しているコードとエラー内容は以下のようになっています。
spresense arduino のバージョンは 2.1.0 です。（2.0.2でも同一でした）

```c
#include <LTE.h>

#define LTE_APN       "soracom.io"  // replace your APN
#define LTE_USER_NAME "sora"        // replace with your username
#define LTE_PASSWORD  "sora"        // replace with your password

char  host[] = "harvest.soracom.io";
int   port = 8514;
LTE           lteAccess;
LTEUDP        lteUdp;
int   ad_value = 0;

void setup()
{
  /* Initialize Serial */
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  ad_value = analogRead(PIN_A4);

  //************************************************************
  // LTE setting
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  Serial.println("LTE Start");
  while (true) {
    if (lteAccess.begin() == LTE_SEARCHING) {
      if (lteAccess.attach(LTE_APN, LTE_USER_NAME, LTE_PASSWORD, LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_CHAP, LTE_NET_IPTYPE_V4V6, false) == LTE_CONNECTING) {
        Serial.println("Attempting to connect to network.");
        break;
      }
      Serial.println("An error occurred, shutdown and try again.");
      lteAccess.shutdown();
      sleep(1);
    }
  }

  while (LTE_READY != lteAccess.getStatus()) {
    sleep(1);
  }

  Serial.println("UDP Send Start");
  if (lteUdp.begin(port)  == 1) {
    if (lteUdp.beginPacket(host, port) == 1) {
      Serial.println("UDP Data make Start");
      char ad_str[10];
      sprintf(ad_str, "ad=%04x", ad_value);
      lteUdp.write(ad_str, 7);
      if (lteUdp.endPacket() == 1) {
        Serial.println("UDP Data Send OK");
        delay(100);
      } else {
        Serial.println("UDP Data Send NG(endPacket)");
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("UDP Data make NG(beginPacket)");
    }
    lteUdp.stop();
    Serial.println("UDP Send Stop");
  }

  lteAccess.shutdown();  
  Serial.println("LTE End");
  //************************************************************

  sleep(60);
}
```

```
15:26:47.162 -> LTE Start
15:26:52.940 -> Attempting to connect to network.
15:27:01.017 -> UDP Send Start
15:27:01.202 -> UDP Data make Start
15:27:01.202 -> UDP Data Send OK
15:27:01.295 -> UDP Send Stop
15:27:01.295 -> up_hardfault: PANIC!!! Hard fault: 40000000
15:27:01.295 -> up_assert: Assertion failed at file:armv7-m/up_hardfault.c line: 148 task: altmdm_xfer_task
15:27:01.295 -> up_registerdump: R0: 68f10246 00000000 00000010 00000080 0d00e265 00000000 04195404 00000000
15:27:01.295 -> up_registerdump: R8: 00000000 000186a0 00000002 00000000 00000080 0d050960 0d028271 0d029f24
15:27:01.342 -> up_registerdump: xPSR: 41000000 BASEPRI: 000000e0 CONTROL: 00000000
15:27:01.342 -> up_registerdump: EXC_RETURN: ffffffe9
15:27:01.342 -> up_dumpstate: sp:     0d0357a8
15:27:01.342 -> up_dumpstate: IRQ stack:
15:27:01.342 -> up_dumpstate:   base: 0d035800
15:27:01.342 -> up_dumpstate:   size: 00000800
15:27:01.342 -> up_dumpstate:   used: 00000148
15:27:01.342 -> up_stackdump: 0d0357a0: 000005dc 0d00dfe3 000000e0 00000000 00000000 00000080 0d050960 0d028271
15:27:01.342 -> up_stackdump: 0d0357c0: 0d029f24 0d0357d0 0d00e32f 00000003 00000000 0d00e337 0d00e315 0d01cc5f
15:27:01.342 -> up_stackdump: 0d0357e0: 000000e0 0d01908d 000000e0 0d05088c 00000000 04195404 00000000 0d00e293
15:27:01.342 -> up_dumpstate: sp:     0d050960
15:27:01.389 -> up_dumpstate: User stack:
15:27:01.389 -> up_dumpstate:   base: 0d050a58
15:27:01.389 -> up_dumpstate:   size: 000005dc
15:27:01.389 -> up_dumpstate:   used: 00000240
15:27:01.389 -> up_stackdump: 0d050960: 00000080 00000000 00000000 00000018 00000000 0d028d5f 0d03f7b0 0d034288
15:27:01.389 -> up_stackdump: 0d050980: 0d03f7b0 0d050108 0000000c 0d025fcb 00000000 0d025fbf 0d03f7b0 0d00f859
15:27:01.389 -> up_stackdump: 0d0509a0: 0d050118 0d050094 0d050198 0d00f8a3 0d050050 00000000 0d04fec0 0d010df1
15:27:01.389 -> up_stackdump: 0d0509c0: 00000001 0d04fec0 0d045f50 0d050050 00000000 0d00adbf 0d000504 00000000
15:27:01.436 -> up_stackdump: 0d0509e0: 0000000c 00000000 00000000 0000000c 0d04fec0 0d04fec0 0d04f680 0d010b93
15:27:01.436 -> up_stackdump: 0d050a00: 0000000c 0d00ad45 ffffffff 0d04f5b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d0124c7
15:27:01.436 -> up_stackdump: 0d050a20: 00000000 0d050a5c 00000008 4b4f4b4f 00000101 00000000 00000000 00000000
15:27:01.436 -> up_stackdump: 0d050a40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d00b09f 00000000 00000000 deadbeef 0d050a64
15:27:01.436 -> up_taskdump: Idle Task: PID=0 Stack Used=0 of 0
15:27:01.436 -> up_taskdump: hpwork: PID=1 Stack Used=576 of 2028
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=2 Stack Used=352 of 2028
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=3 Stack Used=352 of 2028
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=4 Stack Used=352 of 2028
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: cxd56_pm_task: PID=6 Stack Used=352 of 996
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: <pthread>: PID=7 Stack Used=312 of 1020
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: init: PID=8 Stack Used=1440 of 8172
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: lte_daemon: PID=9 Stack Used=992 of 4068
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: thrdpool_no01: PID=10 Stack Used=592 of 2004
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: thrdpool_no02: PID=11 Stack Used=528 of 980
15:27:01.483 -> up_taskdump: altmdm_xfer_task: PID=12 Stack Used=576 of 1500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

analogRead()を呼び出した後にLTE begin(), shutdown()を呼び出すと
analogReadから使用さるADCのリソースが解放されてしまい
それが原因でエラーを引き起こしていました。

修正版を開発ブランチにアップしました。
https://github.com/SPRESENSE/spresense-arduino-compatible/releases
SPRESENSE beta release (2021/04/10)
sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx@23dc3f5 arch: cxd56xx: Fix multiple open and close ADC driver

開発ブランチのArduinoパッケージを使用する方法はこちらを参考にしてください。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_プレリリース_spresense_arduino_board_package_パッケージのインストール](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9_spresense_arduino_board_package_%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)

ご指摘ありがとうございました。
本修正は来月予定の正式リリースに反映される予定です。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Answer (score 0):

送信周期が1分以上あって他に何の処理もしないのであれば、deepSleep を使うのはどうでしょうか。

#include <LowPower.h> と、setup() に LowPower.begin() を追加して、
sleep(60) の代わりに LowPower.deepSleep(60) を使います。
(lteAccess.shutdown() を呼ぶと確かにエラーが発生するのでコメントアウトしています)

私が普段使っているやり方ですが、これが最も省電力になります。参考まで。

```c
#include <LTE.h>
#include <LowPower.h> // ★追加

#define LTE_APN       "soracom.io"  // replace your APN
#define LTE_USER_NAME "sora"        // replace with your username
#define LTE_PASSWORD  "sora"        // replace with your password

char  host[] = "harvest.soracom.io";
int   port = 8514;
LTE           lteAccess;
LTEUDP        lteUdp;
int   ad_value = 0;

void setup()
{
  /* Initialize Serial */
  Serial.begin(115200);

  LowPower.begin(); // ★追加
}

void loop()
{
  //************************************************************
  // LTE setting
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  Serial.println("LTE Start");
  while (true) {
    if (lteAccess.begin() == LTE_SEARCHING) {
      if (lteAccess.attach(LTE_APN, LTE_USER_NAME, LTE_PASSWORD, LTE_NET_AUTHTYPE_CHAP, LTE_NET_IPTYPE_V4V6, false) == LTE_CONNECTING) {
        Serial.println("Attempting to connect to network.");
        break;
      }
      Serial.println("An error occurred, shutdown and try again.");
      lteAccess.shutdown();
      sleep(1);
    }
  }

  while (LTE_READY != lteAccess.getStatus()) {
    sleep(1);
  }

  ad_value = analogRead(PIN_A4);

  Serial.println("UDP Send Start");
  if (lteUdp.begin(port)  == 1) {
    if (lteUdp.beginPacket(host, port) == 1) {
      Serial.println("UDP Data make Start");
      char ad_str[10];
      sprintf(ad_str, "ad=%04x", ad_value);
      lteUdp.write(ad_str, 7);
      if (lteUdp.endPacket() == 1) {
        Serial.println("UDP Data Send OK");
        delay(100);
      } else {
        Serial.println("UDP Data Send NG(endPacket)");
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("UDP Data make NG(beginPacket)");
    }
    lteUdp.stop();
    Serial.println("UDP Send Stop");
  }

  //lteAccess.shutdown(); // ★削除
  Serial.println("LTE End");
  //************************************************************

  LowPower.deepSleep(60); // ★sleep(60)から置き換え
}
```

Comment: kzzさん回答ありがとうございます。
deepsleepの使用方法は参考にさせて頂きます。

記載していなくて申し訳ないですが実際のソースでは
他にDIのチェックやgpsの受信を行っておりまして
deepsleepでの回避ができないのです。

Answer (score 0):

LTEを定期的に、かつ時間を置いて使う場合eRDXというLTEの省電力機能を使うのはいかがでしょう。
Arduinoのリファレンスにはないのですが、SDKの以下のAPIはArduinoでも使えるようです。

[5.13.5.7. モデムを省電力設定にする](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E7%9C%81%E9%9B%BB%E5%8A%9B%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

1. [lte_set_edrx_sync](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/developer-tools/api-reference/api-references-spresense-sdk/group__lte.html#gab6317fba4d99cc9ab225e50da969ed43)
   Modemに対してeDRXのパラメータを設定するAPI
2. [lte_get_current_edrx_sync](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/developer-tools/api-reference/api-references-spresense-sdk/group__lte.html#ga14718e197077eed95127b008dca0ee1f)
   ModemとNetworkのネゴシエーション結果を取得するAPI

```
#include "lte/lte_api.h"
    
void setup()
{
  lte_edrx_setting_t settings = {
      .act_type = LTE_EDRX_ACTTYPE_WBS1,  /* Cat.M */
      .enable = LTE_ENABLE,               /* eDRX 有効化 */
      .edrx_cycle = LTE_EDRX_CYC_65536,   /* 655.36秒間隔でModem起床 */
      .ptw_val = LTE_EDRX_PTW_256         /* Modem起床時2.56秒起き続ける */
  };
    
  /* lteAccess.begin() 等の処理をここで行う */
    
  ret = lte_set_edrx_sync(&settings);
  if (ret)
    {
      printf("Error to set a eDRX parameter. ret = %d\n", ret);
    }

  /* lteAccess.attach() 等の処理をここで行って接続を完了させる */

  ret = lte_get_current_edrx_sync(&settings);
  if (ret)
    {
      printf("Failed to get eDRX settings. ret = %d\n", ret);
    }
  else
    {
      /* eDRX の設定結果が確認できる */
      printf("eDRX act_type = %d\n", settings.act_type);
      printf("eDRX enable = %d\n", settings.enable);
      printf("eDRX edrx_cycle = %d\n", settings.edrx_cycle);
      printf("eDRX ptw_val = %d\n", settings.ptw_val);
    }
}
```

Comment: cmmさん回答ありがとうございます。
試しに変更して実行してみたところ
lte_get_current_edrx_syncにて enable の値が 0 で帰ってきますので
ENABLEになっていない感じです。
lteAccess.bigin() の前に設定値を格納して　
lteAccess.bigin()  と lteAccess.attach()　の間で lte_get_current_edrx_syncを実行
エラーなしで、　接続完了後にlte_get_current_edrx_sync()しています。
ソラコムのSIM接続では有効にならないのでしょうか？

Comment: ソラコムさんのSIMは確かeDRXに対応してるSIMもあったかと思いますが、すべてのプランで対応しているのかは分かりません。
lte_get_current_edrx_sync()はネットワークとのネゴシエーション結果なのでAttachし接続に成功した後にしか正しい値は返ってきません。
”lteAccess.getStatus()”で状態が"LTE_READY"であることを確認してからlte_get_current_edrx_sync()を呼んでいますか？

Comment: ソラコムさんのplan-D で他社の通信モジュールの情報ですがeDRXとPSMに対応しているようです。　”lteAccess.getStatus()”で状態が"LTE_READY"であることを確認してからlte_get_current_edrx_sync()を呼んでいます。